# Remove specific values contained in DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to check if a specific value is contained anywhere in a certain column of my dataframe. I am using the following code, where it should clear data containing "0.0". However, it seemed like it is clearing data that does not contain "0.0" as well.

```
mydataset = mydataset[mydataset['Latitude'].astype(str).str.contains('0.0') == False]
```

Example of the data as follows. Highlighted in *red* are data being removed, upon applying the above code.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: `mydataset = mydataset[~mydataset['Latitude'].astype(str).eq('0.0')]` ? or if they are floats `mydataset = mydataset[~mydataset['Latitude'].astype(str).eq(0)]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is problem `.` in regex is special char, so need `regex=False` or escape it by `\`, for invert mask use `~`:

```
mydataset = mydataset[~mydataset['Latitude'].astype(str).str.contains('0.0', regex=False)]
```

Or:

```
mydataset = mydataset[~mydataset['Latitude'].astype(str).str.contains('0\.0')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a pandas dataframe you can conditionally drop rows from your dataframe in the following manner:

```
mydataset = mydataset[str(mydataset.Latitude) != '0.0']
```

If you are trying to remove all 0 values and not just 0.0 then don't convert to string and it should drop any 0 value.